# Stop execution of the simple function using context

Tags: go, concurrency

As far as I understand, the main purpose of the context library is to stop the execution of all the **children's RPC's and HTTP requests**. Or in simple language, we can say that with the help of context library we can pass triggers to the **function calls**.

Here is the abstracted form of problem which I want to solve using context.

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func PrintAndStop(ctx context.Context, numberOfTimePrint int, msg string) {
    communicationChannel := make(chan bool)
    go func() {
        for i := 0; i < numberOfTimePrint; i++ {
            fmt.Println(msg)
            time.Sleep(time.Second)
        }
        communicationChannel <- true
    }()
    select {
    case <-communicationChannel:
        fmt.Println("process has been completed")
    case <-ctx.Done():
        fmt.Println("closing call from the main function")
    }
}

func main() {
    ctx := context.Background()
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(ctx, 3*time.Second)
    defer cancel()
    PrintAndStop(ctx, 5*time.Second, "testing")

    time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)
}
```

Output for the following code is:

```
testing
testing
testing
closing call from the main function
testing
testing
```

link for the following code snippet is present here: https://play.golang.org/p/4Ntwn3wYOiT
`PrintAndStop` is a method that prints some message at an interval of 1sec for a given number of times.
With the help of context library, I want to give control to the main function to stop the execution of `PrintAndStop` whenever it wants. `time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)` at the end of main is just the representation that the main function doesn't end after the function call.

I am aware of the following refactoring, But the actual problem can't be refactored this way.

```
func PrintAndStop(ctx context.Context, numberOfTimePrint int, msg string) {
    completed := true
    for i := 0; i < numberOfTimePrint; i++ {
        select {
        case <-time.After(1 * time.Second):
            fmt.Println(msg)
        case <-ctx.Done():
            fmt.Println("closing call from the main function")
            completed = false
            break
        }
    }
    if completed {
        fmt.Println("function execution is completed")
    }
}
```

**Note**: I am happy to use some extension of `context` library or some completely new library in Go to solve the above problem.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to give control to the main function to stop the execution of `PrintAndStop` whenever it wants

Then you need to check for cancellation of the context *within that loop*:

```golang
    go func() {
        for i := 0; i < int(timeout/time.Second); i++ {
            select {
            case <-ctx.Done():
                return
            }
            fmt.Println(msg)
            time.Sleep(time.Second)
        }
        communicationChannel <- true
    }()
```

Comment: Are there no other options other than, checking for `ctx.Done()` channel in each execution step?

Comment: That's how context is meant to be used, so no, not really. Why do you want something else? Do you perceive a problem with that approach?

Comment: actually instead of time.Sleep(), actual function call has high CPU intensive computation. I just want to stop that computation as soon as the trigger comes from the main function. (Just like killing some process)

Comment: You cannot "kill" goroutines. You must periodically check to see if the context has been cancelled. If your code runs in a tight loop, you must find the appropriate balance between checking too often, which is inefficient when it's not cancelled, and not checking often enough, and leaving your code running longer than necessary when it is cancelled.

Comment: Thank you, Flimzy, I guess I have to repetitively check for the cancelation of context variable in a balanced way.